# Override keyword throwing an error while compile

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, overriding

I have base class

```
template<typename T>
Class Base {
  Base();

public:
  virtual void myfunc()=0; 
}
```

I have derived class

```
template<typename T>
Class Derived: public Base<T> {
  Derived():Base() {
  }

public:
  void myfunc() override; 
}
```

When I compile `g++ -std=c++0x`, I get the error with the overriding function highlighted,
`error: expected ‘;’ at end of member declaration`
`error: ‘override’ does not name a type`

g++ version is 4.6.

Comment: I think you need to specify `myfunc` as `myfunc()` in your base class, otherwise the override is ill-formed.

Comment: sorry, typo while typing question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

g++ 4.6.3 doesn't support the `override` feature of C++11. When you take away the syntatical errors, this code compiles fine in [4.7.2](http://liveworkspace.org/code/4yc7Hy%243516) and Clang.

Moreover, I think this is what you meant your code to be:

```
template <typename T>
class Base {
   Base();

   public:
      virtual void myfunc() = 0; 
};

template <typename T>
class Derived : public Base<T> {
   Derived() : Base<T>() {}

   public:
      void myfunc() override;
};
```

Answer (score 9):

**override** keyword is not supported by GCC 4.6. If you want to override myfunc, just delete override keyword or upgrade GCC to 4.7 version. (Ref: https://blogs.oracle.com/pcarlini/entry/c_11_tidbits_explicit_overrides)